# Why is this function call ambiguous?

Tags: c++, integer, implicit-conversion, unsigned-integer, integer-promotion

I'm reading the standard and trying to figure out why this code won't be resolved without a cast.

```
void foo(char c) { }

// Way bigger than char
void foo(unsigned long int) { }

int main()
{
   foo(123456789); // ambiguous
   foo((unsigned long int) 123456789); // works
}
```

Here's what it says:

> 4.13 Integer conversion rank [conv.rank]
>
> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined
>   as follows:
>
> — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the
>   corresponding signed integer type.
>
> — The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned
>   char.

In particular, what rustles my jimmies is that it doesn't say ANY unsigned integral type, just unsigned char. My guess is that char is being promoted to an unsigned type via conversion. Is this true?

Comment: Perhaps 123456789U would do it for you.

Comment: "In particular, what rustles my jimmies is that it doesn't say ANY unsigned integral type, just unsigned char. My guess is that char is being promoted to an unsigned type via conversion. Is this true?" - I'd hazard that you're misunderstanding the significance of 4.13 in the Standard... `char` is not being promoted to `unsigned`... the issue is as AndreyT says - that 123456789 is an `int` and it's not clearly better to truncate it as a `char` or pass it as an `unsigned long` (`long` would be just as bad - `unsigned` is not significant here).

Comment: Despite the name, the "integer conversion rank" isn't actually used to rank integer conversions during overload resolution.

Comment: Neither conversion is safe -- one is signed to unsigned and the other is larger type to smaller type -- so why should one unsafe operation win over the other?

Comment: +1 For "rustles my jimmies"

Comment: "it doesn't say ANY unsigned integral type, just unsigned char" - what part are you referring to? In what you quoted I don't see anything that would give any exclusive treatment to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 52):

It has little to do with rank of the type defined in 4.13. 4.13 defined internal rankings used to describe integral promotions and usual arithmetic conversions. They by itself do not directly affect overload resolution. Rankings relevant to overload resolution are defined in "13.3.3.1.1 Standard conversion sequences" and then used in "13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences".

So, it is about rank of the conversion as defined under 13.3. `123456789` is an integer literal of type `int` on your platform. This means that calling both `char` and `unsigned long` versions of your function requires an implicit conversion from `int` to `char` or from `int` to `unsigned long`. In both cases we have conversions of "integral conversion" type. That means that both functions are equally "bad" in this case. Hence the ambiguity.

If one of these functions required a mere integral *promotion* (as opposed to integral *conversion*), it would win the resolution and the call would be considered unambiguous. But alas both of your functions require integral *conversions*.

Comment: Or, another way of looking at it: the function call overload doesn't distinguish between `123456789` and `-123456789`, both are `int`s.  Converting `-123456789` to `unsigned long` could lose data: so in general, a conversion from `int` to `unsigned long` could lose data.  The same is true of `char`.  Now, with the specific constant of `123456789` you can prove that it won't be lost, but the overload rules do not take that into account: the type of `123456789` is `int` on your system, so `int` is used to do overload resolution.